# Populate multiple response items from database query in soap

Tags: xml, groovy, request, response, soapui

I'm trying to make a soap mockservice more dynamic and have come across a bit of a problem. I have no idea how to populate multiple response items with information from database rows. I'll explain the project setup and what I'm trying to do as best as I can.

Project works like this:
1. Application is setup to send off xml requests to a soap mockservice.
2. mockservice uses a groovy script to setup a database connection. It gets relevant rows from the database using information passed in the request.

(The following is the part in trying to figure out)
3. Each row in the database query response will be a seperate item in the response.

An example of what I would like.

Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
     <qdiGetPartyFull xmlns="urn:QDIServices">
        <anItem>3328666</anItem>
        <anItem>3328666</anItem>
     </qdiGetPartyFull>
  </soapenv:Body>
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
     <ItemFullResponse xmlns="urn:Services">
        <ItemFullReturn>
           <ItemReponse>
              <country>qwe</country>
              <county>abc</county>
              <postcode>123</postcode>
              <itemError>
                 <errorCode>0</errorCode>
                 <errorMessage xsi:nil="true"/>
              </itemError>
              <status>xyz</status>
           </ItemReponse>
           <ItemReponse>
              <country>qwe</country>
              <county>abc</county>
              <postcode>123</postcode>
              <itemError>
                 <errorCode>0</errorCode>
                 <errorMessage xsi:nil="true"/>
              </itemError>
              <status>xyz</status>
           </ItemReponse>
           <iError xsi:nil="true"/>
        </ItemFullReturn>
    </ItemFullResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
```

Sorry for poor formatting.

Where I am right now:
I have the database connection returning the rows using groovy I just need to figure out how to place each row into a new itemResponse.

I should also mention that the number of items in the request = number of items / rows in response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

I used a MarkupBuilder to generate the xml then just used context to write the generated xml to a response.

Probably better ways of doing it but this seems to work.

Will post code when I finish it off